# How to ignore records that are matched already in lookup table and able to fetch the next matched records in Talend

Tags: lookup, talend, tmap, data-integration

I am trying to perform a lookup in talend and my table looks like this:

```
order           sku             reference
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_08  912459320
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_09  912459320
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_10  912459320
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_11  912459320
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_12  912459320
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_13  912459320
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_14  912459320
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_15  912459320
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_16  912459320
91245932    8893301500  91245932_8893301500_17  912459320
91245932    9892823400  91245932_9892823400_18  912459320
91245932    9892823400  91245932_9892823400_19  912459320
91245932    9892823400  91245932_9892823400_20  912459320
91245932    9892823400  91245932_9892823400_21  912459320
91245932    9892823400  91245932_9892823400_22  912459320
```

I have xml input as main flow, In input I have order and sku , which is matched with table and respective reference is pulled out. As you can see , there are multiple matches, in output I am getting last matched reference(because unique match is used in tmap).

Expected Output: for First match: 91245932_8893301500_08 in output file
for  second match :91245932_8893301500_09 (but I am getting 91245932_8893301500_17 for all matches )

Comment: can you show what you already tried, your look up configuration (Map, ...) ?

Comment: And what if you use "all matches" instead of "unique match" in tMap ? You should get all  references in your output with this option.  Perhaps I did not fully understand your question and a screenshot could help